# How can I share a single news to social media (facebook, twitter) with show image and title using reactjs

Tags: share

When I share the single page in react using react-share package , the link is correct but the thumbnail image and news title are not show on the social media page. How Can I solve it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ravdY.png)

**N:B: I have to Use ReactJs Framework**

I want the share page look like this page.[I want the share page look like this page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMbBZ.png) but I am getting every time look like this page [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbiUG.png)

**N:B: I have to Use ReactJs Framework**